# Getting The connection was reset error everytime when Posting "select 1 from b" in input field

Tags: php, html, post

I am getting The connection was reset error everytime when I am trying to Post "select 1 from b" in textarea field in simple html form. The HTML form is a simple form with only two html tags (a textarea and a submit button).

[image: Before and After submitting the html form]

This is working fine at my dev machine. But not working on staging server running on linux.

Below is the HTML code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form name="welcome" id="addvdoform" action="http://192.168.4.11/addproduct.php" method="post">
        <table class="smalltext1" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Title : </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <textarea name="data[Videoclips][title]" class="txtboxNone" onkeyup="charcountDynamic(this, 254);" id="VideoclipsTitle" required="required">select 1 from b</textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input value="Submit" type="submit" />

                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

My addproduct.php looks like this simple:

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST) ) {
        print_r($_POST);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `action="addproduct.php"` OR `action="/addproduct.php"` . Try and let me know worked or not?

Comment: I tried both but not working. Please note: submitting the form with other values than  "select 1 from b", its working fine.

Comment: What does `addproduct.php` look like?

Comment: It's working at my end perfectly.

Comment: addproduct.php is simple php file having this code <?php
    if( isset($_POST) ) {
        
        print_r($_POST);
    }
?>

Comment: @Shahid it's working fine at my end (my both files are in the same folder and i use `action = 'addproduct.php'`)

Comment: @Anant - I think this issue is on my staging server but not sure what is the reason. The same is working on my local dev machine and other local machines but not on the the server.

Comment: @Shahid  check these two links:- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1056868    and     https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/uASReL5OxPk    may be some solution will come to you.

Comment: @Anant - Let me check these link and thanks for giving your time.

Comment: @Shahid  you are welcome.And if you get solution let me know also

Comment: @Anant - I check the links and they did not solve my problem. I am facing the issue on multiple machines and I don't think the workaround described in those links will help me. Guessing the issue is on the staging server that I am using. Will update you here if I got the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Still facing the issue. Anyone out there who also experiencing such issue?